# When using esbuild with external react I get Dynamic require of "react" is not supported

Tags: esbuild

I am trying to use esbuild with external react.

here is my esbuild command in my package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "esbuild": "esbuild ./src/index.js --bundle --outfile=dist/esmain.js --loader:.js=jsx --external:react-dom --external:react "
  }
```

when running the command, I get no errors:

```
npm run esbuild

> @1.0.0 esbuild C:\prog
> esbuild ./src/index.js --bundle --outfile=dist/esmain.js --loader:.js=jsx --external:react-dom --external:react


  dist\esmain.js  32.7kb

Done in 13ms
```

The problem is that when I run the program in the browser (chrome), I get this error in the console

```
Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "react" is not supported
    at __require (esmain.js:12)
    at esmain.js:27
    at esmain.js:899
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?  I'm having a similar issue with importing babylonjs, where I'm trying to use external in my bundle so I can just use the cdn version of babylonjs in a script tag but getting similar error

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? It might be the one transforming imports to require

Comment: See https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1944

Answer (score 12):

#### Problem

When you get this error, it means you have `require("react")` somewhere in your `esm` build result.

#### Solution

1. Search for `require("react")` in your build directory e.g. `your-package/dist`
2. Check which dependency has caused this. For me, one of them was `@emotion/styled`

```js
var require_emotion_styled_base_cjs_prod = __commonJS({
  "../../node_modules/@emotion/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.cjs.prod.js"(exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var _extends3 = require_extends();
    var React27 = __require("react");
```

3. Fix it by either

- Adding the package to the external option of esbuild in your `tsup.config.ts` to exclude it from your build.

https://esbuild.github.io/api/#external

tsup.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'tsup';

export default defineConfig({
  entry: ['src/index.ts'],
  dts: true,
  format: ['esm', 'cjs'],
  outExtension({ format }) {
    return {
      js: `.${format}.js`,
    };
  },

  // Add this
  esbuildOptions(options) {
    options.external = ['@emotion/*'];
  },
});
```

- Or, by installing the dependency. In my case, after adding the `@emotion/styled` to my dependencies, there were no `require("react")` in my build results anymore.

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot "Check which dependency has caused this. For me, one of them was @emotion/styled". So for me it was @mui/icons-material. 
Note that you can simply use "external" prop in tsup config instead of "esbuildOptions"
```external: ['react', 'react-dom', '@mui/icons-material']```

Comment: My imported package is in dependencies, but still have problem with dynamic require in myfile.mjs (

Answer (score 5):

If what you were tryinig to do was to  access `react` and `react-dom` from global window scope like `window.React` and `window.ReactDOM`, then this is NOT what esbuil `external` option does.

According to [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#external):

> Instead of being bundled, the import will be preserved (using require for the iife and cjs formats and using import for the esm format) and will be evaluated at run time instead.

On top of that, I assume, esbuild adds some check whether the `require` is supported in the target environment, which in the browser it is not by default. Hence the error.

You would need the [esbuild-plugin-external-global](https://github.com/yanm1ng/esbuild-plugin-external-global#readme) and configure the plugin as such:

```
esbuild.build({
  ...
  plugins: [
    externalGlobalPlugin({
      'react': 'window.React',
      'react-dom': 'window.ReactDOM',
    })
  ]
  ...
});
```

At this point you might need a build script instead of callin `esbuild` with options via command line.

Answer (score 1):

@Sinapcs answer is good, but sometimes the offending module does not provide an ESM version and you don't want to make it a dependency but bundle it into your own module.

In that case, there's a semi-elegant workaround. You can use the `banner` configuration option of esbuild to build your own CJS-to-ESM conversion:

```js
banner: {
  js: `import * as requireReact from 'react';
       import * as requireReactDom from 'react-dom'; 

       function require(m) {
         if (m === 'react') return requireReact;
         if (m === 'react-dom') return requireReactDom;
         throw new Error(\`Unknown module \${m}\`);
       }`
}
```

The banner will be prepended unchanged to esbuild's JS output.

What this will do:

- We insert statements that import the required modules to known identifiers (`requireReact`/`requireReactDom` in this case). There is a *slight* risk of naming collisions with output from esbuild. In that case, just pick different names in your banner.
- We define a `require` function in the output module. That means the generated `__require` wrapper from esbuild in the main body of your module will not fail when called by the offending third-party module. Instead it will call the require function from the banner, which will return the correct module.

Answer (score -2):

What i think from the error is.There is somewhere in the code you have imported react like this which is actually a commonjs convention mostly used in Nodejs but not supported by Browsers

const react = require('react');

So just do a code search within your code editor against require('react') and replace it with the import statement. Hope it will work for you

Comment: It's not necessarily in the user's code, it most probably comes from the bundler loading CJS for externals or smth like that

Answer (score -4):

What are you trying to achieve by marking react as external? Based on what I read in the [doc](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#external), the only use-case I can think of is a website that has the react common js loaded & you want to reuse this code in your script. But then my question was - why have 2 apps on the same page, and on top of that build differently.

No idea if this will help, but I wrote an [article about building create-react-app generated with esbuild](https://how-to.dev/how-to-build-code-generated-by-create-react-app-with-esbuild) - building react code seemed to go pretty smooth, especially comparing to some other frameworks.

Comment: I want to have smaller javascript package so it i downloaded faster to the user machine. the react part should already be there. smaller package might looks less complicated to my fellow developers

Comment: ok, sounds like something you can achieve with splitting: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#splitting